# Find my phone - Will it work if the SIM is removed?

Tags: find-my-phone

To lock, ring or locate the phone I need to have active internet connection. But what if the SIM was removed by someone? Will I still be able to perform lock, ring or locate on my phone?

Comment: You mean to say with the phone's MAC address?

Comment: What do you mean ? I just said that some GSM+GPS chips refuse to enable the GPS if there's no SIM, so maybe the phone has one of them and that's why it's not working.

Comment: Ok. Cool down. :)

Comment: Sorry if that sounded harsh or offensive, I was cool and I still am. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should work, as long as your phone is connected to WiFi.

I just tried it - removed the SIM from my Lumia 920 (running 8.1 preview) and enabled WiFi and location. I was able to successfully refresh the phone's location on the map, as well as lock it and make it ring. For obvious reasons I didn't test erasing the phone ;)

[image]
<sup>(Note the missing SIM icon in the top bar.)</sup>

It's possible that for this to work you need to set your phone to use push notifications, rather than SMS, to communicate with Microsoft's servers. To do so, go to Settings → find my phone, and check the "Always use push notifications..." option.

If your phone is not connected to WiFi, then you're out of luck as without WiFi or cellular connectivity there's no way to communicate with your phone.

Comment: maybe in 8.1 preview ... I'm running the vanilla Windows Phone 8 only called [Nokia Lumia Black](http://www.nokia.com/global/windows-phone-black-update/) software.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

I'm sorry to disappoint you, but I made a simple test with my Nokia 920 and the results are terrible...

**Lock**, **Ring** or simple **Find** do not work without a SIM card (then again, you will need to have one in order to use it to call someone).

Someone might test with a different card number to see if it still performs those actions, but on my attempt, it did not Find, or Ring the phone ... soon I put the card on, it found it and it rang from the previous request.

---

**Updated:**

**from comments:**

Yes, WiFi was always available and I could access all services that only require WiFi (Facebook, Email...) as well GPS was on as I was looking at Drive+ App from Nokia... but never ever the website could send a ring or a find...

**from [Indrek](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/a/5220/88) answer:**

Maybe in 8.1 preview it works fine... I'm running the vanilla Windows Phone 8 only called [Nokia Lumia Black](http://www.nokia.com/global/windows-phone-black-update/) software.

You can check going to Settings > system > "extras+info" and **I also have** under Settings > system > "find my phone" both checkboxes

- Send apps to my phone using push notifications (not SMS)
- Save my phone's location periodically and before the battery runs out to make it easier to find

Comment: Have you tried with Wifi connection?

Comment: Even though on Wi-Fi?

Comment: Yes, WiFi was always available and I could access all services that only require WiFi (Facebook, Email...) as well GPS was on as I was looking at Drive+ App from Nokia... but never ever the website could send a ring or a find...